# Can Model have a relation to the same model type in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I am just starting out in EmberJS and am trying to define a navigation structure.

I would like to have a page object that also has child pages. How would I relate them in a data structure?

Here's what I have so far:

```
        App.Page = DS.Model.extend({
        title:          attr('string',                      { defaultValue:''}),
        url:            attr('string',                      { defaultValue:''}),
        defaultPage:    attr('boolean',                     { defaultValue:false}),
        parentPage:     attr('string',                      { defaultValue:''}),
        children:       attr('string',                      { defaultValue:''}),
        position:       attr('string',                      { defaultValue:'left'}),

        getChildren:function(){
            return App.NavigationController.filterProperty('parentPage',this.get('title'));
        }
    });
```

And here is how I'm using it so far:

```
       this.pushObject(App.Page.createRecord({
            title:          "Page",
            url:            "/page"
        }));


        this.pushObject(App.Page.createRecord({
            title:          "Child of Page",
            url:            "/child_of_page",
            parentPage:     "Page"
        }));
```

Any pointers?

**EDIT WITH EXAMPLES:**

I'm trying your suggestions but am receiving this:

```
pPg = App.Page.createRecord({title:'Page1'});

pPg.get('childen').pushObject(App.Page.createRecord({title:'cPage1', parentPage:pPg}));
// output TypeError: Cannot call method 'pushObject' of undefined

var cPg1 = App.Page.createRecord({title:'cPage1', parentPage:pPg});
var cPg2 = App.Page.createRecord({title:'cPage2', parentPage:pPg});

pPg.get('children').objectAt(0);
// outputs undefined
pPg.get('children').objectAt(1);
// outputs undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, just the same as if you were relating to another models: using `belongsTo` and `hasMany`:

```
App.Page = DS.Model.extend({
    title:          attr('string',                      { defaultValue:''}),
    url:            attr('string',                      { defaultValue:''}),
    defaultPage:    attr('boolean',                     { defaultValue:false}),
    parentPage:     DS.belongsTo('App.Page'),
    children:       DS.hasMany('App.Page'),
    position:       attr('string',                      { defaultValue:'left'})
});
```

No need for the `getChildren` method any more, you just use the `children` and `parentPage` property:

```
var parentPage = App.Page.createRecord({
    title:          "Page",
    url:            "/page"
});
parentPage.get('children').pushObject(App.Page.createRecord({
    title:          "Child of Page",
    url:            "/child_of_page"
}));

var anotherChild = App.Page.createRecord({
    title:          "Child of Page",
    url:            "/child_of_page",
    parentPage:     parentPage
});
```

This will create a `Page` object with 2 children.

There are 2 ways to define a relationship when you create objects - either to tell the parent about a child or to tell the child about a parent, no need to tell both - ember will sync the relationship. **This only applies if you define relations between different models!**

#### Edit

Use `get` with `objectAt` to access the *hasMany* relationship:

- `parentObj.get('children')` - get all children. Note that this is not a regular JS array but an `Ember.Array` thus there is no `[ ]` operator.
- `parentObj.get('children').objectAt(1)` - get specific child.

#### Edit 2

You need to tell both parent and child about their relationship when you are dealing with relation to the same model:

```
var parent = App.Page.createRecord({
    title:          "Page",
    url:            "/page"
});
parent.get('children').pushObject(App.Page.createRecord({
    title:      "Child of Page",
    url:        "/child_of_page",
    parentPage: parent
}));
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crUFE/12/) with working example.

Comment: Ok. I understand what you've put and have implemented it. No errors. Great. Now, I feel this should be simple to do, but... how do I access the children now?

Comment: I'm trying this but am having troubles. See my edit above please.

Comment: THANK YOU. I get it now. It's not enough to simple assign the parentPage in this model, you also have to push it to the parentPage. Thank you for taking the time to answer, you rock!

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko I'm implementing something very similar to your example, and `parent.get('isDirty')` returns false after doing the `pushObject` calls. Do you know why this is the case?